# How to register a custom loss function with keras?

Tags: keras, image-processing, deep-learning, neural-network, loss-function

I am trying to use this custom loss function

```
    # calculate binary cross-entropy loss
    lbce = -(1/N*M) * np.mean(y_actual*np.log(y_pred) + (1-y_actual)*np.log(1-y_pred))
    
    # calculate mean squared loss with normalization
    lmsl = 1/(N*M) * np.mean(np.square(y_pred - y_actual))
    
    # add the two losses together
    loss = lbce + lmsl
    
    return loss
```

I am getting this error  ValueError: Unknown loss function: 'vae_loss'. Please ensure you are using a `keras.utils.custom_object_scope` and that this object is included in the scope.

Does anyone know how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Meh, when you are defining a custom loss for keras don't use numpy. You should either use keras or tensorflow. I recommend you use tensorflow functions.

For example instead of np.mean you should use tf.reduce_mean...