# Unknown optimizer: 'additionalupdatesoptimizer' error Using Keras-Rl2 and tensorflow on Mac M1Pro

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, reinforcement-learning

So I'm using:

- tensorflow 2.13.0 (Tried to use tensorflow-macos 2.12.0 got the same error)
- keras-rl2 1.0.5
- numpy 1.23.5
  I'm working on OpenAI's gym, and get this error:

> File "/Users/tima/AI/BlackJack/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/saving/legacy/serialization.py", line 368, in class_and_config_for_serialized_keras_object
> raise ValueError(
> ValueError: Unknown optimizer: 'additionalupdatesoptimizer'. Please ensure you are using a `keras.utils.custom_object_scope` and that this object is included in the scope

Here's my code:

```py
import random
import gym
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Flatten
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers.legacy import Adam

Adam._name = "Adam"  #if I don't include this, I get an error

from rl.agents import DQNAgent
from rl.policy import BoltzmannQPolicy
from rl.memory import SequentialMemory
env = gym.make("CartPole-v1",
            #    render_mode="human",
               )

states = env.observation_space.shape[0]
actions = env.action_space.n

model = Sequential()
model.add(Flatten(input_shape=(1,states)))
model.add(Dense(24, activation="relu"))
model.add(Dense(24, activation="relu"))
model.add(Dense(actions, activation="linear"))


agent = DQNAgent(
    model=model, 
    memory=SequentialMemory(limit=50000, window_length=1), 
    policy=BoltzmannQPolicy(), 
    nb_actions=actions, 
    nb_steps_warmup=10, 
    target_model_update=0.01)

agent.compile(Adam(lr=0.001), metrics=["mae"])
agent.fit(env, nb_steps=100000, visualize=False, verbose=1)

results = agent.test(env, nb_episodes=10, visualize=True)
print(np.mean(results.history["episode_reward"]))
env.close()
```

Tried changing around tf versions, keras versions, get different errors. This is the most stable combination I found and I still get an error.

Comment: Welcome, Temirlan! Could you please add the full exception stack? Could this [advice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75937343/21350362) of using tensorflow functions (`tf.reduce_mean`) instead of numpy (`np.mean`) be useful?